# Differentiation of a unitary matrix

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $\mathbf{U}$ be a unitary matrix ($\mathbf{UU}^\dagger=\mathbf{1}$). What does this implies for $d( \mathbf{ U U }^\dagger)$? Is it mathematically sound to say:

\begin{equation}
d\mathbf{U} \mathbf{U}^\dagger + \mathbf{U}d \mathbf{U}^\dagger = 0 \implies \mathbf{U} d \mathbf{U}^\dagger = - d \mathbf{U} \mathbf{U}^\dagger\\
\implies d\mathbf{U}^\dagger \mathbf{U} = - \mathbf{U}^\dagger d \mathbf{U}
\end{equation}

i.e. can I treat $\mathbf{1}$ as a constant in normal differentiation and say that "$d\mathbf{1}=\mathbf{0}$"

Comment: You differentiate functions in a certain variable. Are you differentiating with respect to $U$? Or is $U$ a function of some other variable?

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong No, d$\mathbf{A}$ denotes the matrix of infinitisemal elements $da_{jk}$.

Comment: Yes, everything looks fine to me

Comment: @ShuchangZhang Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differentiation of the matrix $\mathbf{1}$ yields $\mathbf{0}$, so this understanding is correct.